# Getting an Unathorized error in Plone, when logged in as an admin

Tags: plone

I'm getting an error when accessing the `/image` view of an Image object. The weird part is that I'm logged in as an administrator, and the Error log shows "Anonymous User (None)" as the user trying to access the image.

How is this possible? What should be the things I should be looking for in this case?

Comment: Have you tried turning on debug authorization? Have you customized workflows at all? Does it happen to all image objects?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a lot weirder if the error log showed "admin" as the user. The fact that it shows "Anonymous" is evidence that it is failing to find your credentials at some point, as you would expect an administrator to never have Unauthorized errors .

Is this a stock Plone image type? I have often seen this sort of error concealing a programming error in my own custom code.

Comment: This is a stock Image object. 

I've just changed the state (meaning I've just published the image to intranet users), I got access to the full screen image view. So, this indicates that I should look at the workflow definition and make adjustments there.

Comment: When creating custom workflows you need to assure that you set the `View` and the `Access contents information` permissions exactly the same. When a user only has one of both permissions you may get strange errors like this one. Maybe its because those permissions are set differently for a role?